# cp: cannot stat ... : No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, scp

---

**EDIT**

when I run `$ stat /Users/argenticdev/www/projects/nickeleres/nickeleres.tar.gz`

I receive:

`16777220 1624366 -rw-r--r-- 1 argenticdev staff 0 4692346 "Mar  5 10:40:49 2015" "Mar  5 10:40:11 2015" "Mar  5 10:40:11 2015" "Mar  5 10:40:08 2015" 4096 9168 0 /Users/argenticdev/www/projects/nickeleres/nickeleres.tar.gz`

---

I have even declared an absolute path to my `.tar.gz` and it wont work.  Here is the command:

`scp -v -oPORT=4444 /Users/argenticdev/www/projects/nickeleres/nickeleres.tar.gz root@nickeleres.com:~`

The terminal log of the scp command returns without exiting the script, and Im left with a blinking cursor on an empty line:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host nickeleres.com, user root, command scp -v -t ~
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to nickeleres.com [192.241.221.71] port 4444.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA b8:b5:0b:ed:f0:2d:51:82:6c:95:d8:99:28:e9:69:fd
debug1: Host '[nickeleres.com]:4444' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/nickeleres/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nickeleres/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@nickeleres.com's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to nickeleres.com ([192.241.221.71]:4444).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t ~
/Users/argenticdev/www/projects/nickeleres/nickeleres.tar.gz: No such file or directory
nickeleres@nickeleres:~$ debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Sink: scp: /Users/argenticdev/www/projects/nickeleres/nickeleres.tar.gz: No such file or directory
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2652, received 2308 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 8563.9, received 7453.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Well, does the file exist? What's the output of `stat /Users/argenticdev/www/projects/nickeleres/nickeleres.tar.gz`, and `namei -mo /Users/argenticdev/www/projects/nickeleres/nickeleres.tar.gz`? Are you on OSX?

Comment: I am on OSX, and yes, the file does exist.  should I run those on server or local?

Comment: see edited post above for log

Comment: The scp output looks like it was run on Ubuntu and not on OSX (note all the references to `/home/nickeleres/`, which looks like a typical Linux home directory).

Comment: this is my first go with linux.  thanks for the help